# pyspark dataframe replace null in one column with another column by converting it from string to array

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to replace a null value of a pyspark dataframe column with another string column converted to array.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

new_customers = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["Karen", ["a"]], ["Penny", ["b"]], ["John", [None]], ["Cosimo", ["d"]]], schema=["name", "val"])
new_customers.printSchema()
new_customers.show(5, False)

new_customers = new_customers.withColumn("new_val", F.coalesce(F.col("val"), F.array(F.col("name"))))

new_customers.show(10, truncate=False)
```

But, it is

```
 root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- val: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+------+---+
|name  |val|
+------+---+
|Karen |[a]|
|Penny |[b]|
|John  |[] |
|Cosimo|[d]|
+------+---+

+------+---+-------+
|name  |val|new_val|
+------+---+-------+
|Karen |[a]|[a]    |
|Penny |[b]|[b]    |
|John  |[] |[]     |
|Cosimo|[d]|[d]    |
+------+---+-------+
```

what I expect:

```
+------+---+-------+
|name  |val|new_val|
+------+---+-------+
|Karen |[a]|[a]    |
|Penny |[b]|[b]    |
|John  |[] |[John] |
|Cosimo|[d]|[d]    |
+------+---+-------+
```

Did I miss something ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you've an array with `null` element in it. It will not test positive for `isNull` check.

First clean up single-null-element arrays:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

new_customers = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["Karen", ["a"]], ["Penny", ["b"]], ["John", [None]], ["Cosimo", ["d"]]], schema=["name", "val"])
+------+------+
|name  |val   |
+------+------+
|Karen |[a]   |
|Penny |[b]   |
|John  |[null]|
|Cosimo|[d]   |
+------+------+


new_customers = new_customers.withColumn("val", F.filter(F.col("val"), lambda x: x.isNotNull()))
+------+---+
|name  |val|
+------+---+
|Karen |[a]|
|Penny |[b]|
|John  |[] |
|Cosimo|[d]|
+------+---+
```

Then, change your expression for array empty check instead of null check:

```py
new_customers = new_customers.withColumn("new_val", F.when(F.size("val")>0, F.col("val")).otherwise(F.array(F.col("name"))))
+------+---+-------+
|name  |val|new_val|
+------+---+-------+
|Karen |[a]|[a]    |
|Penny |[b]|[b]    |
|John  |[] |[John] |
|Cosimo|[d]|[d]    |
+------+---+-------+
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I still got "John -> []", my pyspark version is 2.3.2

Comment: my spark has no "filter()".