# pyspark daatframe empty array still got size as 1?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My question is relevant to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73684433/pyspark-dataframe-replace-null-in-one-column-with-another-column-by-converting-i), but it got a new problem.

Why the empty array has non-zero size ?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

new_customers = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["Karen", ["a"]], ["Penny", ["b"]], ["John", [None]], ["Cosimo", ["d"]]], schema=["name", "val"])
new_customers.printSchema()
new_customers.show(5, False)
new_customers = new_customers.withColumn("new_val", F.size("val"))

new_customers.show(10, truncate=False)
```

The results:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- val: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+------+---+
|name  |val|
+------+---+
|Karen |[a]|
|Penny |[b]|
|John  |[] |
|Cosimo|[d]|
+------+---+

+------+---+-------+
|name  |val|new_val|
+------+---+-------+
|Karen |[a]|1      |
|Penny |[b]|1      |
|John  |[] |1      | <- # why it is 1 ? 
|Cosimo|[d]|1      |
+------+---+-------+
```

pyspark version is 2.3.2

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is just a display issue, since you have a list with 1 element `None`. Spark 3.3.0 will correctly display:

```
|John  |[null]|1      |
```

If you remove `None`, you get:

```
|John  |[] |0      |
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 1 because `None` is a valid element.

```
["aa"] -> size 1
[None] -> size 1
[]     -> size 0
```

If you change your initial data to

```
new_customers = spark.createDataFrame(data=[
    ["Karen", ["a"]],
    ["Penny", ["b"]],
    ["John", []],  # Empty array instead of array with None element.
    ["Cosimo", ["d"]]
], schema=["name", "val"])
```

You will get your expected result.

```
+------+---+-------+
|name  |val|new_val|
+------+---+-------+
|Karen |[a]|1      |
|Penny |[b]|1      |
|John  |[] |0      |
|Cosimo|[d]|1      |
+------+---+-------+
```

If you cannot change your input dataframe, you can try removing the None before the `size` function.

```py
new_customers = new_customers.withColumn('new_val', F.size(F.expr('filter(val, x -> x is not null)')))

new_customers.show()

# +------+---+-------+
# |name  |val|new_val|
# +------+---+-------+
# |Karen |[a]|1      |
# |Penny |[b]|1      |
# |John  |[] |0      |
# |Cosimo|[d]|1      |
# +------+---+-------+
```